# What do `data-fir-if` HTML tags reference?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was recently looking over the code found in Google Firebase's `quickstart-js/firestore/` repo, when I came across the following `html` in `index.html`:

```
 63       <header id="site-header" class="mdc-toolbar mdc-toolbar--fixed">          
 64         <div id="title" class="mdc-toolbar__row mdc-layout-grid">               
 65           <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start">
 66             <span class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon--menu">restaurant</span>
 67             <span class="mdc-toolbar__title">FriendlyEats</span>                
 68           </section>                                                            
 69         </div>                                                                  
 70         <div id="section-header" data-fir-if="hasSectionHeader"></div>          
 71       </header>                                                                 
 72   </div>
```

This element is then referenced in `firestore/scripts/FriendlyEats.View.js/` in the `FriendlyEats.prototype.render()` function:

```
407     'data-fir-if': function(tel) {                                              
408       var field = tel.getAttribute('data-fir-if');                              
409       if (!that.getDeepItem(data, field)) {                                     
410         tel.style.display = 'none';                                             
411       }                                                                         
412     },
```

My question here: what does the `data-fir-if` tag mean, and is that some sort of naming convention? If so, what is that naming convention and where might I find a reference for it?

Comment: As for the conventions, I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028211/what-is-the-standard-naming-convention-for-html-css-ids-and-classes) can be enlightening. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML attributes that begin with "data-"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) are used to store data inside that attribute, typically to be used in relation to whatever is being represented by that element.  If you follow the code closely, you'll see that it relates to how the element is displayed.  The code is specifically saying that if the item in question doesn't have a field with the given name, then don't display it.